# Power method in Matlab giving inconsistent results

Tags: matlab, recursion, linear-algebra, eigenvector

I'm trying to make a simple implementation of the power method for determining dominant eigenvectors of a matrix in Matlab. If you repeatedly multiply any vector by a matrix, normalize that, multiply again and repeat, it should converge to an eigenvector of the matrix corresponding to eigenvalue of greatest absolute value.

This is what I tried:

```
A1=[13 6;-12 -5]
x=[1;1]
y=(1/norm(x))*x

powerMethod(A1,y,4)

function yn=powerMethod(A,y0,n)
    if n>0
        x1=A*y0
        y1=(1/norm(x1))*x1
        powerMethod(A,y1,n-1)
    else
        yn=y0
    end
end
```

I thought it was working fine at first. When `x=[-1;1]` it converges to `[-0.7071;0.7071]` which is correct. The actual eigenvectors of the matrix are `(-1,1)` and `(-1,2)`. But when I changed `x` to `[1;1]`, now it converges to `[0.7072;-0.7070]` which isn't an eigenvector of the matrix at all. `x=[1;1]`, `[1;10]`, and `[1;1000]` all converge to basically the same vector. What am I doing wrong to make different values of `x` converge to a vector that's not even an eigenvector? I don't have a lot of experience with Matlab so I don't know if it's because I'm misunderstanding how the power method works or how Matlab works.

Comment: If `n>0`, you don't assign anything to `yn`, so the function won't have a return value. You also don't collect the return value of the function in the recursive call. But because you don't end any line with a semicolon, all intermediate results are shown, and you might not be noticing that there is no result when you call the function. You should put a `;` at the end of each statement inside your function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm sorry I've been trying to do this but I don't think I understand Matlab functions well enough. Do you think you could give an example?

Comment: Try `ny = powerMethod(A,y1,n-1)` inside your function. -- This is not MATLAB specific, you'd have to do the same thing in any language. When you call a function that returns a value, you assign that value to a variable.

Comment: I've added yn= to that line but it doesn't make any difference to my incorrect results

Comment: Well, you should at least get a result, previously you didn't iterate, and you didn't get an output in the call `powerMethod(A1,y,4)`. (stuff was written to the screen, but the function itself didn't return any values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any non-zero multiple of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector. So your answer is only unique up to a non-zero scalar multiple. In particular, if e is an eigenvector then so is -e. Your two answers are correct, they just converge to opposites because of your starting point. You can do the multiply by hand to prove it to yourself:

```
>> A1 * [-0.7071;0.7071]
ans =
  -4.949700000000000
   4.949699999999999
>> ans/norm(ans)
ans =
  -0.707106781186548
   0.707106781186547
>> A1 * [0.7072;-0.7070]
ans =
   4.951600000000000
  -4.951400000000000
>> ans/norm(ans)
ans =
   0.707121061700346
  -0.707092500384339
```

Also, your function doesn't need to be recursive. Just put the calculations in a loop. E.g.,

```
A1=[13 6;-12 -5]
x=[-1;1]
y=(1/norm(x))*x

e = powerMethod(A1,y,20)

function yn = powerMethod(A,y0,n)
yn = y0 / norm(y0);
for k=1:n
    yn = A * yn;
    yn = yn / norm(yn);
end
return
end
```

Comment: I think I was just not fully understanding eigenvectors but you cleared it up for me thank you